# How do i turn multiple usb ports off based on multiple sensors

Tags: transistors, usb, sensor, serial, i2c

I'm looking for a way to turn a usb port on an off from an Arduino, I'm looking at purchasing something like [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00BWF5U0M) and somehow using a pressure or light sensor to turn the usb port on and off. I was thinking that I could use a transistor or relay to turn the usb port on and off, however, I may need to have many sensors ( maybe 20 ) that turn USB ports on and off, and the Arduino pins would fill up pretty quick. Perhaps there is such thing as a serial or i2c transistor? that way they could all be on a bus of some sort.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by 'switching off a USB port', but  if your problem is controlling multiple relays from 3 I/O pins  the TPIC6C595 (http://focus.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tpic6c595.pdf) might be the answer

Comment: I'm sorry, I thought it was clear, I just want to switch the power of the usb port on and off, I have a powered USB speaker that I'm trying to turn on and off

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using a GPIO expander for this. I have used the Microchip [MCP23017](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/21952b.pdf) in the past for this very setup. This device is a 16 channel programmable GPIO available in either SPI, or I2C (the part number is slightly different for SPI).

[image: MCP23017 Functional Diagram]

You can connect the gpio outputs from this device to N-Channel mosfets with a pull-down resistor to achieve your goal. The best thing about this part is that it is available in a dip package for cheap ($1.44) at [DigiKey](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/MCP23017-E%2FSP/MCP23017-E%2FSP-ND/894272).